# Confused About Why I have no extension methods available

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, .net-core

I'm implementing a Unit OF Work pattern (not my choice, I know it's considered by some as an anti-pattern).

I've come across a situation I don't fully understand.

My generic repo constructor:

```
this.context = context;
this.dbSet = context.Set<T>();
```

Generic method:

```
public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<T>> All()
{
    return await dbSet.ToListAsync();
}
```

Using it like this:

```
var languages = await _unitOfWork.Languages.All();
languages = languages.OrderBy(x => x.Order);
```

As shown above, I need to go down a line so I can use OrderBy,
I don't understand why.

A second question is, `ToListAsync` is supposed to return a list, why do I get an `IEnumerable`?

Comment: `List` is an implementation of `IEnumerable`.

Comment: 2. because you wrote this (`All()`) way  ... 1. obviously  you can't  use `_unitOfWork.Languages.All().OrderBy(x => x.Order)` because All returns `Task<T>`

Comment: You don't have to "go down a line" but what `All` is returning is a `Task` and so you need to `await` it before you get an `IEnumerable<T>` to work with. The `await` up until the `All` could be enclosed in parentheses and then you could `OrderBy` from there.

Comment: because of `await` ... you may obviosuly use `var languages = (await _unitOfWork.Languages.All().)OrderBy(x => x.Order);`

Comment: May be you are using another `ToListAsync`? As far as I understand you want to use `ToListAsync` from `EntityFramework.dll`, in this case you should check dependency on `EnityFramework.dll` and check for using on `System.Data.Entity`, where extension method is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion as far as having them on the same line seems to be on how it's applying the `await`. This should work fine:

```
var languages = (await _unitOfWork.Languages.All()).OrderBy(x => x.Order);
```

You need to do this because your `All` function is returning a `Task` while `OrderBy` is not.

Additionally, you probably don't want to call `.ToListAsync()` in the first place, that's just a `SELECT *` without any limit or where clause which may not be the "end of the world" all the time but often will be extremely detrimental to your performance.

As for your second question about why it's returning an `IEnumerable<T>` it's because `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` and your function signature indicates that it returns `IEnumerable<T>`

```
public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<T>> All()
```

I highly recommend instead of ever dealing with `.ToListAsync` or `IEnumerable<T>` you leave it alone and let `IQueryable<T>` do its proper work against the database.

**EDIT**: It's been asked in comments why it matters that you'd use `IQueryable<T>`. The answer is because utilizing `.Where`, `.Any()` etc... against `IQueryable` will mold the underlying query against the DB.

For example, say you want to find a single entity with the `Id` of `123`. If you leave your `.ToListAsync()` without any other modifications it will pull back every single row in the DB into your program in memory and then iterate every single row looking for that one row.

If, instead, you use `IQueryable<T>` - at the point where you apply `.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 123)` it will be applied to the database and it will apply as something like `SELECT TOP(1) * FROM MyEntity WHERE [Id] = 123` - pulling back ***a single row*** instead of every row in existence.

**EDIT2**: Note that this also applies to projection. This means something like `.Select(e => new { FullName = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName, State = e.Address.State})` will only pull those 2 columns instead of all columns and any nav properties you include. Doing that after a `.ToList()` or `.ToListAsync` will instead pull back all columns/entities and iterate over them to create a whole new set of other entities. This can result in MASSIVE CPU/Memory differences between the 2 approaches.

Comment: How is IQueryable better?

Comment: @Kosta - I've edited my answer to expound upon `IQueryable<T>`

Comment: Great answer, I'm new to C# and has learned something new :)

Comment: Very detailed answer , Thanks !

Comment: @Kosta, If you are going to return `IQueryable<T>` - then don't bother with own "Unit of Work" implementation, because `DbContext` is exactly that - implementation of `Unit of Work` ;)

Comment: @Fabio Unfortunately its not up to me, a company policy ,
But noted!

Answer (score 3):

> A second Question is, ToListAsync is suppose to return a list, why do I get an IENUMERABLE?

[`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0) is an implementation of `IEnumerable`. Check [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface).

> As shown above, I need to go down a line so I can use OrderBy, I don't why.

`_unitOfWork.Languages.All()` returns a `Task`, you should get its unwrapped result of `IEnumerable` to apply `OrderBy` on it.

To make this work as you expected, you should apply `OrderBy` on the awaited result:

```cs
(await _unitOfWork.Languages.All()).OrderBy(x => x.Order);
```